# Eclipse Auto Complete: Java 1.7 Generics Diamond

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, autocomplete

I just upgraded to Luna (from Kepler) and I noticed some little (yet annoying) problem:
The auto completion lacks the possibility to generate diamonds "<>" for already specified generics in variable initialisation. For Example, when I type:

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet
```

I would expect, that it gets auto-completed to

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
```

rather than

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>();
```

I am using JDK 1.7 and the compliance level is set to 1.7 also.

Its also very strange that when I hit STRG+Space multiple times during auto-completing till it reaches java-autocompletion again and then hit Enter it delivers the expected diamonds.

This looks very much like a bug to me.
Is this bug "known" and is there any workaround for this issue? Could not find anything related to this topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have most likely installed the **Code Recommenders** plug-in. Unfortunately this plug-in is affected by [bug #435597](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435597) which breaks this functionality.

This bug appears to occur only if you have certain *proposal kinds* enabled in the “*'default' content assist list*” (*Eclipse Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced*). For example I could get back the correct behavior by disabling the following proposal kinds:

- Basic Proposals
- JPA Proposals
- Template Proposals

(the last one is likely the most annoying if you are using code templates…)

When you are cycling with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, you are actually reaching the “*Java Proposals*” (instead of the “*Intelligent Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)*”), which is not affected by this bug.

This bug is scheduled for [release 2.2.0](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.recommenders/releases/2.2.0) in June 2015. **The best you can do** for the moment is:

- **Play with the proposals** to check which ones trigger the bug for you (maybe take a screenshot of your current setup before doing that);
- **Vote** for [bug #435597](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435597) and [bug #435660](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435660) to get them fixed;
- **Propose patches** for fixing those bugs :-)

Comment: Many thanks for this helpful answer! 
Strangely the diamond bug gets fixed for me, when I only select "Intelligent Java Proposals" as default proposal kind as you can see in [this](http://i.imgur.com/5vUVbbD.png) screenshot.

Comment: Yes if you only enable that one it should always work. Note that the ones you select in the bottom table do not trigger the bug so you can keep access to them through cycling with ctrl+space.

Comment: Cool! To me the "basic" proposal was giving me the trouble. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

For anyone still experiencing this with the latest Eclipse version:

Open "Window" > "Preferences" > "Java" > "Editor" > "Content Assist" > "Advanced". In the opened dialog under "Default Proposal Kinds":

- Check "Java Proposals"
- Uncheck "Java Proposals (Task-Focused)"

[image: Proposal kind selection]

Answer (score 2):

`Set` is an interface rather than an implementation so the IDE can only assume that you want an anonymous inner type which always requires the generic type parameter. You could do

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet + CTRL + SPACE
```

Comment: Yes, I just mistyped. I meant the Implementation HashSet not Set. But this doesn't work either.

Comment: I have Luna Build 20140612-0600. Is this M7? Where can I see this version part?

Comment: It's in `Help->About`. Interesting when I tried this on a newer version of Luna, the same issue occurred. When I used an earlier version it didnt occur

Answer (score -4):

This diamond feature is introduced in jdk 1.8 it does not work with jdk 1.7.
So it is the new feature introduced by oracle .

Thus this will only depend on the jdk version on your computer not the ide version..

Comment: Thats not true. It was introduced with 1.7 and it does compile when I type it manually. The point is: The auto-complete doesn't do it automatically anymore. [see eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-with-java7.htm)