# Eclipse style code complete for generic types - Use Diamond

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

My autocomplete in Eclipse always provide the generic type with the constructor. Since it is not necessary in the newer version of Java since java 7 I'd like my autocomplete to only provide <> instead.

```
List<String> strings = new Arraylist<String>();
```

would become

```
List<String> strings = new Arraylist<>();
```

I had a look at code templates, but couldn't find anything interresting.

Thanks

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using? Your problem sounds similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984135/eclipse-auto-complete-java-1-7-generics-diamond).

Comment: Spring Tool Suite 
Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201503100339
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)

Comment: Yes! Thnaks! the solution proposed fixed my problem. I didn't know we call it a "diamond".

Comment: @azurefrog, why not make your comment an answer?

Comment: @Steve Because I didn't answer the question; I just steered the OP toward an existing answer that might fix their problem.

Comment: FYI - diamond notation started in Java 7