# Eclipse autocomplete always adds diamond brackets

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

- Eclipse Version:2018-09 (4.9.0)
- Plugin "Code Recommenders for Java Developers": 2.5.4.v20180909-1131

My Eclipse autocompletion does a little more than I like when it completes generic classes.

**Example:**

```
when(component.method(param)).thenReturn(Opt... [Press Strg+Enter])
```

Current Behavior

```
when(component.method(param)).thenReturn(Optional<Type>)
```

Wanted Behavior

```
when(component.method(param)).thenReturn(Optional)
```

I only want to complete the class name in order to call a static method (`Optional.of(...)`), but now I first have to delete the type and the diamond brackets.

**What I found so far**

This is old but partly similar: [Eclipse Auto Complete: Java 1.7 Generics Diamond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984135/eclipse-auto-complete-java-1-7-generics-diamond)

The wanted behavior in this case is an empty diamond operator when creating a new instance. This issue seems to be fixed since 2014.

The plugin *Code recommenders* is mentioned there and that you can specify what eclipse will offer as autocompletion at

```
Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences
-> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced
```

Turning of the options "Java Proposals" and/or "Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)" will stop this behavior... because it turns of absolutely all Java Code recomendations.

May the force be with you!